# Fingerprint for a student visa at the Spanish embassy

Tags: student-visa, spain

I'm about to apply for a Spanish student visa. And I want to know whether they are going to collect my fingerprints at the Spanish embassy or not. Thank you.

Comment: For completeness, where are you applying from? Have you given fingerprints for a Schengen visa previously (within the last 59 months)?